# Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{1-x}\ln\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the Maclaurin series expansion (power law series) of the function:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\ln\frac{1}{1-x}.$$

I could find the expansion terms, up to the 5-th term, and is:

$$F(x) = x + \frac{3}{2!}x^2 + \frac{11}{3!}x^3 + \frac{50}{4!}x^4 + \frac{274}{5!}x^5 + \dots$$

and so on...

But I could not find a closed formula for it. Does any exist?

I've tried manipulating the power law series for $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ and $\ln(1+x)$, but without success...

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+log(1%2F(1-x))%2F(1-x)) agrees with your expansion and  will give terms at least up to $x^{33}$ by clicking on More Terms, but does not give a closed form

Comment: The closed form of $F(x)$ is $f(x)$, which you started out with... up to the fifth term you could factor out an $x$ but that's as closed as you're going to get ! Or maybe you could write it as a product of the two power series corresponding to $1/(1-x)$ and $\ln(1+x)$ where expansion would produce powers of $x$ up to the 5th power only. For this you would write the power series of one up to the $x^n$ term and the other up to the $x^m$ term, where you choose $n+m=5$, presumably $n=2$ and $m=3$ or vice-versa. But the usual way is to just expand the function as it is up to the 5th term.

Comment: I mean a closed formula of a power law serie. I'm thinking of a cauchy product, but need some help on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 1/(1-x)ln(1/(1-x)) = $$
$$ (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)(x+x^2/2+x^3/3+x^4/4+...) = $$
$$ x+(1+1/2)x^2+(1+1/2+1/3)x^3+(1+1/2+1/3+1/4)x^4+...= $$
$$ x + 3x^2/2 + 11x^3/6+25x^4/12+...=$$
$$ \sum_{a=1..\infty } (\sum_{b=1..a} 1/b) x^a =$$
$$ \sum_{a=1..\infty} H_a x^a$$

Numerators of harmonic numbers $H_n$ : https://oeis.org/A001008

Denominators of harmonic numbers $H_n$ : https://oeis.org/A002805

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{1 \over 1 - x}\,\ln\pars{1 \over 1 - x} =
> -\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 - x}}$ is the
>   [Harmonic Number Generating Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generating_functions).

Namely,
\begin{align}
{1 \over 1 - x}\,\ln\pars{1 \over 1 - x} =
-\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 - x} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\, x^{n}
\end{align}

> $\ds{H_{z}}$ is a [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\ds{\quad n\quad} & \ds{\quad H_{n}\quad}
\\ \hline
\ds{1} & \ds{1}
\\ \hline
\ds{2} & \ds{3 \over 2}
\\ \hline
\ds{3} & \ds{11 \over 6}
\\ \hline
\ds{4} & \ds{25 \over 12}
\\ \hline
\ds{5} & \ds{137 \over 60}
\\ \hline
\ds{6} & \ds{49 \over 20}
\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$